# PHPmailer's AddEmbeddedImage method not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to test the PHPmailer class to embed image (http://www.google.gr/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png) inside an e-mail

I'm using this code (along with standard one, that 100% works, mail is delivered):

`$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($src, 'test', basename($src));`

and this is placed the e-mail body:

`<img src="cid:test">`

Image is not showing up. What may I doing wrong?

Comment: You can not embed-attach images from URL, you need to have a copy of the file on disk. What value has `$src` in your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taken from some piece of the documentation:

> $path is the path of the filename. It can be a relative one (from your
>   script, not the PHPMailer class) or a full path to the file you want
>   to attach.

Have you tried using a local image?

Answer (score -4):

cid:test isn't valid url for image.

Comment: it is when it comes to images embedded within an e-mail